# Can I use my GPU from a docker container on a MacBook Pro ? (AMD Radeon GPU)

Tags: macos, docker, gpu, macos-sierra

I would like to run a GPU enabled app (Gazebo) inside a docker container on my MacBook Pro.

I seemed to me, through my research, that about a year ago, Docker released a native Docker app for MacOS.

Before that, Docker used to spawn an entire Linux VM and run the container on top of it.

Now, it apparently uses some native hypervisor framework, making it more optimized and closer to the hardware, changing entirely Docker's approach to containerization on a Mac.

All this is not very clear to me and I am not sure of everything I stated.

**Is it now possible to use my macbook pro's GPU from a docker container, and, if yes, how ?**

The command line I'm using right now, which works for regular X11 apps but not GPU-enabled apps like Gazebo is:

```
xhost +
docker run -it -e DISPLAY=$ip:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix image_name bash
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way of running Gazebo inside a container deb0ch?

Comment: Nope, never did :/

Comment: 2020 update: you might want to take a look at https://ade-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ where there is experimental support for OSX. No GPU and display is quite slow but, technically, Gazebo is running in a container on MacOS. An example image for Turtlebot3 is available at https://gitlab.com/deb0ch/ade-turtlebot3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### There's still a virtual machine involved.

Docker for Mac uses a virtualization layer called [XHyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve). It's a lot thinner and more lightweight than VirtualBox or such (emulates fewer peripherals), but it's still virtualization.

---

#### PCI passthrough is (theoretically) possible, but you can't pass through your laptop's main GPU and still use it.

Hardware with an IOMMU (and yes, your MacBook Pro has an Intel chipset with such support) can allow a virtualized environment direct access to PCI hardware.

However, you can't cede control of a piece of hardware to a VM and still use that hardware from the host. (Some high-end server network cards work around this by having multiple PCI endpoints, so the host and each guest gets a different endpoint to talk to).

---

#### So -- you could get an external Thunderbolt-attached GPU, and it might work... *in the future*.

[The underlying support in Xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve/issues/108) isn't there yet (as of this mid-2017 writing), and even on KVM (used by a lot of folks doing pioneering work here), there are only limited reports of success (with a specific video card -- the Radeon HD 5850).

Comment: If you can't cede control of a piece of hardware to a VM and still use it from the host, how come my VMware VM can use the GPU at the same time as my host ?

Comment: @deb0ch, if your guest and host can use the GPU at the same time, the host is clearly *not* ceding full control (which involves mapping the memory and interrupts straight through to the guest, and thus not even seeing them itself). You can still provide a virtualized driver that provides partial access and acts an intermediary; there's a performance penalty, but if you want to share access, there you are.

Comment: So is it possible (if Docker or Apple implement it in the future) to provide similar partial access to the GPU to a container ?
By the way, thank you very much for your helpful insights :)

Comment: Yup, possible, if folks build support in the future. It's not just VMware that supports shared access already -- there's OSS native Linux support in the form of [virtio-gpu](https://www.kraxel.org/blog/tag/virtio-gpu/), but I haven't heard of anyone building something similar for MacOS/xhyve.

Comment: BTW, speaking to the state of affairs in early 2021 -- nVidia explicitly supports PCI passthrough with their cards aimed at business markets (f/e, the Quadro series); whereas with consumer cards, their drivers refuse to install if they detect a virtualized environment. AMD cards can still be passed through, though resetting them when rebooting a VM (to be able to reboot a VM but not the host) isn't well supported (requires 3rd-party software) except in Big Navi units that are currently very rare and hard to find. And AFAIK, none of this is supported in Xhyve.

Comment: ...and continuing that early-2021 update: nVidia's professional-grade cards _do_ have extra PCI endpoints that can be individually passed through, just as high-end network cards did in 2017. But unless you're getting ready to drop ~$5k on a GPU, that's not very likely to be relevant to the consumer market (and out-of-the-box Docker isn't a suitable runtime environment for that use in any event).