# How do I give GPU access to Docker on Mac

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gpu, open3d, amd-gpu

I've been running into some issues with trying to get Docker to work properly with my GPU. A bit of background on what I'm trying to do - I'm currently trying to run Open3D within a Docker container (I've been able to run it fine on my local machine), but I've been running into the issue of giving my docker container access.

I'm not entirely sure what is needed, and most of the guides or details has been in regards to Nvidia and Ubuntu, without much detail on how to get it work with a Mac.

I've tried a few things with the docker-compose file - here it is right now, thought I feel like I'm in the wrong direction.

```yaml
services:
  cmake:
    container_name: cmake_container
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    
    tty: true
    command: /bin/bash

    volumes:
      - ./testdata_files:/app/testdata_files
    
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: amd
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Here are my graphics details:

- AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 8GB
- Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use my GPU from a docker container on a MacBook Pro ? (AMD Radeon GPU)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46367517/can-i-use-my-gpu-from-a-docker-container-on-a-macbook-pro-amd-radeon-gpu)